# Is there a "If (X increase)" function?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm making a game with XNA. 
I have my camera, my background and my scrolling class ready to go.

All i lack is to tell the scrolling to work when the camera position change. Is there a statement for that?

Like:

```
if (cameraposition.X ""Increases"")
{
    Scrolling.Update()
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You'd either have to register to handle an event on the cameraposition or on the X value (if they support it) or remember the old value and compare. I suspect there might be an event?

Comment: I don't really know XNA, but look for something like a `CameraPosition.Change` event.

Comment: Be careful with events in game development. Usually polling is used, just check the desired state every frame.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to keep track of the old camera position, and see if it changes. So your if would be:

```
if(cameraPosition.X != oldCameraPosition.X)
```

At the end of every frame you want to update the oldCameraPosition variable, as such:

```
oldCameraPosition = cameraPosition;
```

The difference between both positions is usually called the delta, or velocity. Now for the scrolling you might call your update with the camera Delta, so you scroll the same (or a modified amount). For example:

```
//In Camera.cs
Scrolling.Update(oldCameraPosition - cameraPosition);

//In your scrolling class
void Update(Vector3 offset)
{
 background.Position += offset * .5f;
}
```

That way, every time the camera moves your background plane moves with it, at half speed. Do that trick 3 times with different modifiers and you'll have a paralex effect.

Normally you'd want to use events for this, however an exception can be made for Game Development. Polling usually is the way to go, since you already have a game loop much like an event loop. 
Either way, it would make more sense to just call `Scrolling.Update()` whenever you change the position of your Camera in the first place.

Comment: For pure "increase", do `if(cameraPosition.X > oldCameraPosition.X)`

Comment: @Attila: camera position could decrease too, so != is a correct choice. If there is any *difference*, pick that *difference* and apply it to scroll: that is the logic, basically.

Comment: @Trigan - OP asked for "increase"

Comment: Seems good to me. 
I'll had an oldcameraposition state.
Then a 
     if(cameraPosition.X > oldCameraPosition.X)
OR
     if(cameraPosition.X > oldCameraPosition.X)

depending on the scrolling i want

Comment: @Attila true, but sometimes you can help the OP solve problems he doesnt even have yet ;) And its easy enough to change.

Comment: I'll make like the KeyboardState and oldKeyboardState thing.

Answer (score 3):

It's naturally performance choice, but what if you simply say :

```
 Scrolling.Update(cameraPosition.X, cameraPosition.Y)
```

If the scrolling is already in valid position, will not change anything.

Should be measured, naturally, before used. In this way you will avoid to store *state* variables, or addional variables to store "old" information.

Comment: A good alternative, but it could cause issues if you want to ease towards the new position. Often the position you stop at wouldnt be exactly the same as the desired position, so the backgrounds could stutter a lot.